# iOS Local Notifications repeat x times

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am creating an app that should ask the user to come back every day in december for a christmas-story.

What is the best way to manage the local notifications?

- Create 24 (or as many as the number of stories) local notifications - through for(){}
- I saw the parameter "repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount" when displaying the local notifications to the log - can I in any way set that, so I can create 1 notification, repeat it every day and set the limit for 24?

Also, does it create the local notifications again, if the app creates the local notifications each time it is started? Or does is overwrite the existing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the individual notifications and if it creates them every time your app opens you can simply cancel them all and recreate them.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

//create your notifications
```

Comment: Do you know what the `repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount` does? Or how to change it - can't seem to find an answer anywhere?..

Comment: that has the format of being a constant but I can't find it in documentation. It does look like there can be a repeat where you pass in an interval length but that will likely lack flexibility if you wanted to skip days or something. I've used the method I've mentioned more than once very successfully.